# Как получить поле записи по индексу, как элемент массива?

Tags: freepascal

На самом деле вопрос немного сложнее.
Проблема заключается в этом небольшом кусочке кода:

```
assign(InputFile, FilePath);
reset (InputFile);
```

Так как программа (из которой взят этот фрагмент) должна принимать значения из файлов двух разных типов (один text, другой file of longint), значит и проводить две вышеуказанные операции нужно по идее два раза:
*объявление записи*

```
  InputFile : record
    case isTyped : boolean of
      true: (WithInts : file of longint);
      false: (WithText : text)
  end;
```

*сам код*

```
if isText = true then begin
  assign(InputFile.WithText, FilePath);
  reset (InputFile.WithText);
end
else begin
  assign(InputFile.WithInts, FilePath);
  reset (InputFile.WithInts);
end
```

Вопрос - а можно ли не городить этого ветвления, а сделать что-то вроде:

```
assign(InputFile[i], FilePath);
reset (InputFile[i]);
```

Этот пример чисто концептуален, главное сделать код как можно чище и короче.
Собственно, выделять из двух одинаковых частей один отличающийся элемент довольно тяжело.
Я очень много способов пересмотрел, но так ни одного подходящего не нашел.
Или способ оказывался слишком сложным для понимания, или слишком громоздким в написании, или вообще не должен по идее работать. Пробовал variant, assembler (не разобрался), бестиповые указатели (нужно явно разыменовывать).
Любому кто напишет решение буду искренне благодарен.

Comment: Чище? Не используйте рекорды с `case`.

Comment: Да я бы и сам рад, да вроде это позволяет использовать рекорды как аналог union из сей.

Comment: "использовать рекорды как аналог union" - Не является уважительной причиной.